# Phantom Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I am working an on Android app.  Today a "phantom" emulator has appeared on my system.  It shows up when I have NOTHING connected and I run "adb devices".  I steals "logcat" output when I am developing in Eclipse and I can't see the REAL emulator I start to tun my app.

When I start a single emulator, I actually have two.

The only change I made recently is to install the WIMM emulator (see www.wimm.com).  I don't start that one however.

Any clues would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It happens to me too sometimes. I do

"adb kill-server"

"adb start-server"

and usually it connects again.
Although I don't know why that happens. I'm very new to android...

Answer (score 1):

Try to running

"/path/to/android-sdk/tools/android update adb"

follow by:

"adb kill-server"

"adb start-server"

This should fix your problem. It's probably due to the recents adb tools changes when you install the WIMM Add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

I had something like this.

ADB watch some port to check if emulators are launched. I had an application using the port 5555.

So type the following command (unix / mac / linux) :

```
lsof -i -P | grep 5555
```

It will give you the application and pid that use the port :

```
uHD-Netwo   320  jva    7u  IPv4 0x07b77338      0t0  TCP localhost:5555 (LISTEN)
uHD-Netwo   320  jva   16u  IPv4 0x0861b788      0t0  TCP localhost:5555->localhost:55265 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Then simply kill the app :

```
kill -9 320
```

The emulator shouldn't be there anymore.